# How to set Forms Auth cookie expiration in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, owin

In the `Login` method of my `AccountController` I have the following:

```
var claims = new List<Claim>();
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, model.UserName));
AuthenticationManager.SignIn(
  new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = model.RememberMe,
                                 ExpiresUtc = expiry },
  new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie));
```

where `expiry` is a calculated `DateTimeOffset` value.

No matter what I set for the `expiry` value the expiration of the `.AspNet.ApplicationCookie` is always 14 days.

Is there any way to customize this expiration value?

Is it related to https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/workitem/115 ?

Note that in `Startup.Auth.cs` I do not have the `ExpireTimeSpan` property set. When I do set that property its value is respected, and the approach above still does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed in [this commit](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/a2c810d30a2946b2e064091e013781e56016df94#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs) on Apr 16, 2014.

```
    protected override async Task ApplyResponseGrantAsync()
    ...
    DateTimeOffset issuedUtc = Options.SystemClock.UtcNow; 
(-) DateTimeOffset expiresUtc = issuedUtc.Add(Options.ExpireTimeSpan);
    context.Properties.IssuedUtc = issuedUtc; 
(-) context.Properties.ExpiresUtc = expiresUtc;
(+) if (!context.Properties.ExpiresUtc.HasValue)
(+) {
(+)     context.Properties.ExpiresUtc = issuedUtc.Add(Options.ExpireTimeSpan);
(+) } 

    Options.Provider.ResponseSignIn(context); 

    if (context.Properties.IsPersistent)
    {
(+)    DateTimeOffset expiresUtc = context.Properties.ExpiresUtc ?? issuedUtc.Add(Options.ExpireTimeSpan);
       cookieOptions.Expires = expiresUtc.ToUniversalTime().DateTime;
    }
```

Comment: I wanted to point out one other thing that someone might run into if they're debugging cookie expiration with Owin. Apparently the interval at which the authentication cookie expiration is checked is defined by the CookieAuthenticationProvider.OnValidateIdentity property.  The interval set by a project created from an MVC5 template that uses OWIN identity will be 30 minutes.  So the auth cookie might be expired but it won't time out the user's session until that interval is hit.  The code to modify this is in ConfigureAuth method in Startup.Auth.cs: `validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)`